# Distinct layouts vs one responsive layout to handle different device sizes and orientations

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, single-page-application

I have specific layouts for any combination of desktop/tablet/smartphone and portrait/landscape. In the context of a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), is it better to separate the layouts as different resources and load them using some javascript/css logic to detect device type and orientation or to have a single html/css resource and differentiate the layout using some complex media query/decoration logic?

For the former option I see the cons of duplication, because it is likely that the layouts for the same section share a consistent amount of ui elements; for the latter I see it could be very complex to handle all different combination of device size/orientation inside the same html/css, especially if the layouts have significant differences between each other.

What is the best approach and why?

Answer (score 1):

You should use media-queries. They are much better because you will not have to rewrite all of the code, you would only need to change the things that actually need to get changed and leave the rest as it is. This lets you reuse the same HTML instead of having a different HTML for mobile, desktop, tablet etc...

It will be much less work than making a separate page for every screen size...

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second option, it will be easier to manage the CSS rather than duplicating everything, DRY is the best way to work in this case.

If you are using a preprocessor such as Sass or Less then it will be easy to add in some conditions at the bottom of your stylesheet to give additional styles for each orientation.

Here is some more information on the principle of DRY:
http://vanseodesign.com/css/dry-principles/

**Some of the key aspects are:**

- Group reusable css properties together
- Name these groups logically
- Add your selectors to the various css groups

**Keeping things organised with media queries**

With the main chunk of styling at the top of the page, media queries such as these for mobile, mobile portrait and mobile landscape can then be used to add any tweaks as needed:

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am using sass preprocessing with gulp. In case layouts between devices are significant different between each other, does it make sense to have a responsive layout specific for each device (handling orientation with media queries)? The problem here is not the css but the different structure in the html for each type of device..Or must I strive to have one single html layout at any cost?

Comment: Unless the actual content is changing for each device the HTML will stay the same. Media queries are used to show, hide and manipulate bits of HTML depending on device, like mobile navigation for example. The HTML is the same in each view.